# addClass on click function, single vs. multiple

Tags: jquery, addclass

```
$('#form').addClass('hide');

$(document).ready(function () {
  var count = 0;

  $('#cat3,#cat2,#cat1').click(function () {
    count += 1;

    if (count == 3) {
        $('#form').removeClass('hide');
    } 
 });
})();
```

I have 4 divs, cat1,cat2,cat3 and form. After each cat div is clicked once, form appears. Right now, you can click one cat 3 times to make the form appear. I'd like each cat to have its own click function and contribute to the count. once the count reaches 3, #form appears.

I don't think i'm too far off, but I am unsure how to separate the click counters so each can only be clicked/counted once. Any ideas?

my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aztVY/253/

Answer (score 1):

I'd just set a data attribute on each, and then check if the length equals 3.

```
$('#form').addClass('hide');
var count = 0;
$('#cat3,#cat2,#cat1').click(function () {
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
    if ($('#cat3,#cat2,#cat1').filter(function () {
        return $(this).data('clicked') == true
    }).length == 3) $('#form').removeClass('hide');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/aztVY/254/)**

Answer (score 0):

This is just another way, using a class and `.one()`:

```
$('#form').addClass('hide');
$('#cat3,#cat2,#cat1').one('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    if ($('.clicked').length == 3) $('#form').removeClass('hide');
});
```

### -DEMO-

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vq3bxgoe/) out:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var count = 0;
  var divsClicked = [];
  $('#cat3,#cat2,#cat1').click(function (event) {
     if(divsClicked.indexOf(event.target.id) < 0){
        divsClicked.push(event.target.id)
     }

    if (divsClicked.length == 3) {
        $('#form').removeClass('hide');
        divsClicked = [];
    }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I appreciate your help. Here's what I ended up doing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#form').addClass('hide');
var hintCounter = 15;

$('#cat15,#cat14,#cat13,#cat12,#cat11,#cat10,#cat09,#cat08,#cat07,#cat06,#cat05,#cat04,#cat03,#cat02,#cat01').click(function () {
    // check if has hints
    if (hintCounter > 0) {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("highlighted")) {
            hintCounter--;
        }

    $('.xHints').html(hintCounter + ' Cats Left to Find');
    } else {
        // else show the message out of hints
    }
    $(this).addClass("highlighted");
   if (hintCounter == 0) {
        $('#form').removeClass('hide');
    } 
});
</script>
```

and here's the application in production: http://www.worldsbestcatlitter.com/facebook/whisker-wonderland/